# Vue3 unwrap properties in typescript class

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-reactivity

I am experiencing a strange behavior with Vue3 where Vue unwrap my passengers property in my typescript class (I don't need to write .value to access it). Futhermore, depending on how the function is called, sometimes it unwrap and sometimes it doesn't (so sometimes It needs .value and sometimes It doesn't). According to Vue documentation, Refs should only be unwrapped in the template, so this behavior is unexpected.

Here is an exemple of my typescript class :

```
class Car {
    passengers:Ref<Passenger[]>;

    ...

    getNumberPassenger():number
    {
        // One of the two is working, the other not
        let nbPassengerA = this.passengers.value.length;
        let nbPassengerB = this.passengers.length; 
        return nbPassengerA;
    }
}
```

A)
After debugging, I've found that if the instance of the typescript class is wrapped in a proxy, I don't need to use .value. So my first question is :
Why do Vue3 unwrap ref, that is outside template, if the function is called from a proxy ?

```
// carA is an instance of Car
carA.getNumberPassenger(); // nbPassengerA work but not nbPassengerB

// carB is a proxy that contain an instance of Car
carB.getNumberPassenger(); // nbPassengerB work but not nbPassengerA
```

B)
Initially, my typescript class is not a proxy and a ref, it's just an instance stored in a let. However, it seems that Vue automatically converts the instance to a proxy in certain cases. I'm not entirely sure what the conditions are for this phenomenon to occur.

Here's a basic example to illustrate my issue (although this example actually works correctly):

```
class Person {
  name: string;
  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

class Car {
  driver: Person;
  constructor(driver: Person) {
    this.driver = driver;
  }
}

const driver = new Person("John");
const car = new Car(driver);

console.log(driver); // driver is an instance

// Here, the `driver` object has been automatically converted to a proxy
const carRef: Ref<Car> = ref(car);
console.log(driver); // driver is a proxy
```

I am currently using toRaw to retrieve the instance, but this is only a temporary solution because the underlying issue is not yet resolved. If I were to embed another class as a property in a class that is in a Ref in the near future, the problem would arise once again.

Comment: When looking into the [Vue documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref), you will find, that vue will create a reactive object of any object you pass to the ref function. This is why it will be an Proxy. Also interesting to read: https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-in-depth.html#how-reactivity-works-in-vue

Comment: The question would be why should there be a reactive property on a class? This would only make sense, if you would have something else react on a change of this value. Inside a class, you can use getters and setters to perform side effects or use javascript Proxy to track changes in the object.

Comment: Yeah I understand that when you create a reactive object of an object, it's a proxy. But the thing is, I didn't pass the object to the ref function. In my exemple, carA is a proxy but I didn't pass it to a ref, I stored it like a regular variable. Do you think It's possible that vue retrieve the proxy if carA has been pass to a ref in another script ?

Comment: Yes, a component use this property, so I need passengers to be a ref.

Comment: I still think, that a class is not the right way to go. I don’t know exactly, what you want to achieve, but I could imagine that you could also have a composable that does what your class is doing right now.

Comment: In these reactive frontend frameworks it makes often sense to think more in a functional than in a object oriented way.

Comment: Oh, I never thought to use composables like that, I will check this out. Thanks !